# JQuery get img src and use it in a as data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a javascript library which requires a specific HTML structure but unfortunately I am not allowed to change it. 
The structure comes from a template and I have to work with what I have.
The point is that I try to copy every image's src and put it in  as data-largesrc="image/source/here".
Any clue how I could do this? I have this until now but it's not working as intended:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").attr('data-largesrc', "'" + $("a").children().attr('src')) + "'");
});
```

And the HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="products" class="productsList main">
        <ul id="og-grid" class="list og-grid">
            <li class="l1 i1 column1">
                <a href="?17,barracuda-email-security-gateway" tabindex="-1">
                    <img src="files/150/BARRACUDAESG.jpg.png" alt="BARRACUDAESG.jpg.png">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure this should be solved rather easy but I can't seem to find a solution. Thank you very much if you can help me!

Comment: What is the code that you have doing and how is it different from what you intended?

Comment: Get rid of the `"'"` and use `.data()` instead

Comment: @Cameron637 that is the code that I've tried. It doesn't change anything. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong but not sure what. The point is to copy the path in <img src="path/to/img"> in its parent <a> as <a data-largesrc="path/to/img">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each($("a"), function(i, k){
    $(this).data("largesrc", $(this).find("img").attr("src"));
  });
});
```

Comment: To be honest, this seems to be the most appropiate to what I'm looking for. Still, It retuns undefined and I don't get why...

Answer (score 0):

The `children()` method returns **all** direct children of a parent element. In other words, it will return an array. What you are looking for is a single object.

Anyways, it would be best to use the `data()` function instead

```js
function getImageSource() {
    var imgSrc = $("img").first().prop("src");
    $("img").data("largesrc", imgSrc);
    var data = $("img").data("largesrc");
    $("#img-data-value").html(data);
}

$("button").on("click", getImageSource);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="products" class="productsList main">
        <ul id="og-grid" class="list og-grid">
            <li class="l1 i1 column1">
                <a href="?17,barracuda-email-security-gateway" tabindex="-1">
                    <img src="files/150/BARRACUDAESG.jpg.png" alt="BARRACUDAESG.jpg.png">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<button>Get Image Source</button>
<p id="img-data-value"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need the extra quotation marks.  Second, you should use .first() instead of .children() because .children() will return an array whereas .first() will return the first child (and yours only has one child).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").data('largesrc', $("a").first().attr('src')));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Real working script

```
let targetButton = $('.your-btn');
    if (targetButton.length) {
        targetButton.each(function (){
            let self = $(this),
                term = self.data('image');
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                let img = $(this).closest('.parent-class').find('img.target-class');
                img.attr('src', term);
                        
            });
        });
    }
```